# Does the variable v have a reference(pointer) to each StringBuilder object in the array?

Tags: variables, pointers, for-loop, reference, each

```
StringBuilder Arr[]={new StringBuilder("what"), new StringBuilder("happens")};

for(StringBuilder v : Arr)
    System.out.println(v);
```

Does the variable v have a reference(pointer) to each StringBuilder object in the array?

Answer (score 0):

The for each statement is syntactic sugar for a classic for loop. So this statement for an array:

```
for(StringBuilder v : Arr)
    System.out.println(v);
```

Is the equivalent of this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < Arr.length(); ++i)
    System.out.println(Arr[i]);
```

And `Arr[i]` is a reference to ith object when `Arr` contains objects.